# What does "soaring heights" mean?

Tags: meaning

> As Mr. Schuester (Matthew Morrison) guides the glee club to **soaring
>   heights**, his personal life grows increasingly complicated, his
>   nemesis Sue Sylvester (Jane Lynch) devises new ways to derail the
>   gang, and several standout singers encounter devastating dilemmas. (https://www.angusrobertson.com.au/videos/glee-season-2---volume-1/p/9321337130156)

I searched, and it doesn't seem to be an idiom. What does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"soaring heights" here means "great achievements". The metaphor is that one is soaring like a bird, high above expectations. It is a somewhat florid or poetic phrase, but not uncommon.

I don't know that I would call it an idiom but it is a common metaphor, perhaps even a cliche, especially when describing an artistic performance.

Answer (score 0):

Fame is often associated with height.

to soar is to rise into the air or be up in the air, like an eagle or hawk or airplane.

The seagull soared around the island.

soaring heights means: heights that "are like flying high in the air".

Skyscrapers are often referred to as having "soaring heights".

soaring heights are ones associated with something that flies high in the air.